# Visual Studio 2010 jump to next arbitrary character/string

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, replace

is there a way to jump to the next brace without using the file command and specifying Find Next?

An example is:

```
foo = function(data1, data2) {

},

bar = function(data3, data4) {

},

baz = function ...
```

and I want to know if there is a keyboard shortcut like Vim's / then 'n' to keep find the next of any arbitrary character? I have a JSON file I'm working on and want to be able to quickly jump to the next opening brace without using my mouse.

I found the jump to matching brace command, but that doesn't help me much.

Thanks for your help and I'm happy to clarify my question or provide more examples if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ctrl+]` to mach an open/closing brace/parenthesis, it's a standard shortcut since at least MSVC 6.0 to my knowledge.

Incremental search is started by `Ctril+i` followed up by a standard `F3` to repeat the last search.

`Ctrl+f` opens a "find text" dialog box